# Calling API id change to slug

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

i want to change my post id to slug. The issues is i'm using API to call the posts. Here example the post when i call it

```
localhost:3000/articles/389996
```

and here the API when i calling it.

```
 "nid": 389996,
"title": "results bundles league",
"created": 1518996078,
"changed": 1518996078,
"field_article_author": null,
"field_article_topic": {
    "tid": 8456,
    "name": "Sports"
},
"field_tags": [
    {
        "tid": 147,
        "name": "fbl"
    },
    {
        "tid": 184,
        "name": "GER"
    },
    {
        "tid": 286,
        "name": "Bundesliga"
    }
],
```

Question is how to change the articles/ID to article/title. Im using RAILS.

Thank you in advance peeps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) gem to achieve this. There's a [railcast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid) for this also if you are using it the first time.

Comment: well, i can achieve that from friendly_id, but data coming from third party API. There no active record involve in here. Any blogs or article that i can read that would be great. Thanks bro.

Comment: I see. But to call your desire API you need the id, right? If so, you need to create a mapping table with slug and post_id. In this way, you will know which id to use for calling the API.

Comment: Allright, im start digging right now. I will update the answer once i got it. Thanks bro.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create url friendly title called slug.

`rails g migration add_slug_to_articles slug:string:uniq`

re-migrate database `rake db:migrate`

```
# article model
before_save :slug_title
def slug_title
   self.slug = title.gsub(" ", "-")
end

# config/routes.rb
resources :articles, param: :slug

# app/controllers/articles_controller.rb

# ...
@article = Article.find_by(slug: params[:slug])
# ...
```

Personally, I would suggest to use [Friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) as @M.Karim mentioned.

```
# article model
extend FriendlyId
friendly_id :title, use: [:slugged, :history, :finders]


def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
    title_changed?
end
```

URL becomes: `localhost:3000/articles/results-bundles-league`